# Visual studio code go to declaration open in new file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have this line:

```
import {isString} from '../util/util';
```

When I am clicking on the isString with the cmd key, it's open the declaration in the same file. However, I want to open this in a new file, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You open file with `import {isString} from '../util/util';` in "Preview mode". You can recognize it by *Italic Titlse*. To pin editor double-click on the title.

When editor is pinned to a screen, declarations will be open in a new tab. This tab, again, will be open in a *Preview Mode*, so you have to pin it when you want it to stay.